# ionic 3 setting image as background for ionic tabs

Tags: css, ionic3

I need to set the tab bar as an image rather a solid color. my tabs.html look like

```
<ion-tabs color="ferrari-bg" class="ferrari-tabs">
  <ion-tab [root]="tab1Root" tabIcon="people-outline"></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab1Root" tabIcon="speedometer"></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab2Root" tabTitle="About" tabIcon="information-circle"></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab3Root" tabIcon="calendar"></ion-tab>
    <ion-tab [root]="tab3Root" tabIcon="film"></ion-tab>

</ion-tabs>
```

and the app.scss

```
.ferrari-tabs{

    background-color: transparent  !important;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.16),0 2px 10px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.12);
    background-image: url("../assets/images/footer.png") !important; background-size: cover; 
 }
```

how it doesnt render the image. in chrome dev console i can see the class is applied but no idea why it is failing to show

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting background for  your *ion-tab**s***. It's size is full screen and it is overlapped by current active tab. So you can not see it. If you want to set background for `tab bar`, just style for `.show-tabbar` class.

```
.show-tabbar{
    background-color: transparent  !important;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.16),0 2px 10px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.12);
    background-image: url("../assets/images/footer.png") !important; background-size: cover; 
 }
```